# Wcf service refuse to connect

Tags: c#, wcf

I have wcf base address https://localhost:9090 when download above get service information but I get error

There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:9090/Notification/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9090
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9090/'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9099/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1: 9090

Please give any solution wcf service base address

Comment: You've got two ports in your post, 9090 and 9099. Not sure if typo or not. And you're sure there is a process running on that port and listening for traffic? Your error message says there isn't.

Comment: Port no 9090 it is typing mistake

Comment: check if any process listening on 9090 by running this cmd `netstat -ano | findstr 9090` ; adding to this looks like you are trying to reach `wcf` service from another machine but unable to, try giving proper machine `ip address` instead of localhost in the `url`.

Comment: Also, try hosting `wcf service` by configuring `base address` with local machines `ip address ` while hosting.

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437914/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message