# testing WCF - There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to unittest a WCF app.
Here what I've tried:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"].ToString();
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}. mykey={1}", value, val);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        try
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:56666/Serivce1";
            var baseAddress = new Uri(url);
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);

            Binding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "Service1");

            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            serviceHost.Open(); // if this fails, you have to run Visual Studio as admin

            BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding);
            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(url); 
            IService1 wcfClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel(myEndpoint);
            string s = wcfClient.GetData(39);

            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)serviceHost).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I call wcfClient.GetData(39);
I get this error:
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:56666/Serivce1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and how to make it work?

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437914/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the port I'm using gets used, but I cannot talk to it even from another program. Note that I had to open VisualStudio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but making the bindings consistent and fixing the issue related to the configuration of the WCF not getting loaded with a not-so-nice workaround:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        string val = "Nothing";
        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings != null && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"] != null) // when normally run
        {
            val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"].ToString();
        }
        else // when run via unittest:
        {
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "web.config";
            Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings"); // this does not work, so I I wrote the loop:
            foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement kv in configuration.AppSettings.Settings)
            {
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
            }

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"] != null)
            {
                val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mykey"].ToString();
            }
        }

        return string.Format("You entered: {0}. mykey={1}", value, val);
    }

}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        try
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:56669";
            var baseAddress = new Uri(url);
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, "");

            var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // enabling server side exception details to help debug:
            var behavior = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
            behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

            serviceHost.Open(); // if this fails, you have to run Visual Studio as admin

            ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding);
            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(url); 
            IService1 wcfClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel(myEndpoint);
            string result = wcfClient.GetData(39);
            Assert.AreEqual(string.Format("You entered: {0}. mykey=myval", 39), result);
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)serviceHost).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to improve the configuration loading would be welcome.