# Can't access external endpoint from IIS-hosted WCF application

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF service, hosted in IIS, that accepts requests from clients and forwards those requests on to an external, third party web (SOAP) service. The 3rd party provider has test and production instances of their service.  My WCF service can reach the test site but not the production site (get the "no endpoint listening at https://..." error).

I wrote a tester (console) app that basically takes the guts of the WCF service and makes the call to the third party service.  When I run this test app on the same Windows server as the IIS-hosted WCF service, it can successfully connect to both the 3rd party's test and prod sites.

Our network folks monitored network traffic during all my testing and can see all activity except for when my WCF service attempts to call the external prod site.  No indication from network traffic logs that my requests to the prod site are leaving the Windows (IIS) server.

At a bit of a loss as to next steps but basically the question is, is there something in IIS that might control / limit access to external IPs?

Any other ideas welcome.

Comment: Enable WCF tracing to learn more of the internals, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing And, also check if a proxy server is required.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at your firewall and network configuration.

Comment: **no endpoint listening at https://..." error** The cause of this issue is due to an incorrect address or a SOAP operation. But it can also be an issue caused by IIS request size limitations. This post has relevant solutions that I think will be helpful to you.[There was no endpoint listening at (url) that could accept the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437914/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message)